# Control visibilty of the custom button dynamcally from specific set of users

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I would like to implement a solution for custom button visbility based on the user. I dont want to create separte profile as there are users from 3-4 different profiles with different privileges. I would like to implement Apex Code with List of UsersId to check. Also, need to know the what we need to include in the test classes for the same.
Thanks,
SF User

Comment: are you display this button in custom VF page.

Comment: No its on standard Opportunity Layout @TusharSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately since it is on the standard layout your options are limited to:

1. Use Page Layouts / Recordtypes to show based on profile (you already said you did not want to do this)
2. Use VF to override the View and roll your own
3. In the Button change it to execute JS and use AJAX toolkit to check a list of settings to match allowed IDs then simply show an alert like "Not Authorized" if the ID does not match and do not execute the rest of the script

item 3 would be the quickest to implement

Comment: variant of option 2 - Use VF + jQuery `css(..)` `display:none` and  `apex:detail` to dynamically hide buttons

Comment: You can thank me by up voting and /or marking the answer as the correct one if it solves your problem

Comment: Button being part of the managed package, doesn't allow editing. Trying to work on creating VF page and extending it to include condition in rendering but not able to achieve

Comment: Wow. That's an important piece of information that u left out of your question.

Comment: I figured out this now. I need to know if we create VF page then how can you associate it. Any links

Comment: Ideally, the package provider should give you a permission set that should allow you to determine which users can access that feature. Perm sets are user-by-user assigned, thus meeting your requirement. Whatever workaround you decide on, go back with this feature request (if it doesn't already exist).